# Can AWS DocumentDB log slow aggregate queries containing a $lookup stage?

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have the profiler enabled on DocumentDB and it is happily logging slow queries (both simple queries and aggregate pipelines). However whenever I execute an aggregate query containing a $lookup stage, it never appears in the slow query logs (despite it definitely being slow).

Can anyone shed any light on why this may be happening?

Comment: If I were to offer an arbitrary guess - that may be an artifact of the implementation. Each iteration of the `$lookup` individually may be completing quickly. So even if the summation of these iterations is slow for the overall aggregation, the measurement/comparison triggering this as a 'slow operation' is not. Probably a good question or improvement request for AWS

Comment: @user20042973 any idea how to ask AWS about this? My company doesn't have a support plan and I can't find any public forums.

Comment: actually never mind, just found the re:post forums. Will ask there, thanks